# inventory using google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a business and im using Gas to confirm and managing, after buyer buy some thing in my shop i will call to confirm ordered if buyer accept order i will put ok on column C of sheet Order, my code will fid product from sheet Inventory and will minus that product founded from column D on sheet Order .But my Code run very long time, i dont want that, example when two my employee call the same time and they put ok the same time GAS can't fast enought to calculate and it just minus 1, who can help me to improve running time of my code or who have another solutions.
Here is my code

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('DATA');
    var range = e.range;
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Inventory");
    var i, j;
    if (range.getColumn() == 3 && (range.getValue() == "ok" || range.getValue() == "cancel")) {
      var fullListStr = ss.getRange(range.getRow(), 4).getValue();
      var listShirts = fullListStr.split(",");
      for (i = 0; i < listShirts.length; i++) {
        listShirts[i] = listShirts[i].trim();
      }
      var listCheck = s.getRange("F1:F5").getValues();
      for (i = 0; i < listShirts.length; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < listCheck.length; i++) {
          if (listShirts[i] == listCheck[j][0]) {
            var row = j + 1;
            var column = 5;
            var currentProduct = s.getRange(row, column).getValue();
            currentProduct--;
            s.getRange(row, column).setValue(currentProduct);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
//    var currentProduct = s.getRange(2, 5).getValue();
//      currentProduct--;
//      s.getRange(2, 5).setValue(currentProduct);
      Logger.log(currentProduct)
      Logger.log(listShirts);
      Logger.log(listCheck);
    }
}
```

And here is my sheet

[image: This is inventory sheet]

[image: This is order sheet]

Comment: What is a "very long time"?

Comment: You'll need to add some comments in your code Minh, a link to your spreadsheet might be useful too, if you can.

Comment: @JayJenkins Sorry i'm a newbie, i have just learning to code 1 month ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The first "for" loop isn't needed. You can combine the `trim()` operation into the other "for" loop.
- The inner "for" loop is not needed. Convert the 2D array of shirt IDs into a 1D array and then search for the index of the shirt ID.  The index of the shirt ID is the same as the row number plus one.
- Don't get the length in the "for" loop - define the length and assign it once.
- Your column number is static, it doesn't need to be assigned in every loop.
- You can get rid of one layer of nested blocks by checking the column number and stopping the code if the edit isn't in the correct column

I haven't tested this code.  I just threw it together.  But it should provide you with the concepts for what you need to do to improve it.

Code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var arrayListCheckIDs,column, currentProduct, i, j, L, range, row, s, ss, thisShirt;

  column = 5;

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('DATA');
  range = e.range;
  s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Inventory");


  if (range.getColumn() !== 3) {return;}
  if (range.getValue() !== "ok" || range.getValue() !== "cancel") {return;}


  var fullListStr = ss.getRange(range.getRow(), 4).getValue();

  var listShirts = fullListStr.split(",");

  L = listShirts.length;


      var listCheck = s.getRange("F1:F5").getValues();

  arrayListCheckIDs = listCheck.toString().split(",");//Convert 2D array to 1D array

      for (i = 0; i < L; i++) {

        thisShirt = listShirts[i].trim();

        row = arrayListCheckIDs.indexOf(thisShirt) + 1;

        if (row === -1) {continue;}//There was no shirt ID found in the array of shirt IDs

            currentProduct = s.getRange(row, column).getValue();
            currentProduct--;
            s.getRange(row, column).setValue(currentProduct);
            break;
      }
//    var currentProduct = s.getRange(2, 5).getValue();
//      currentProduct--;
//      s.getRange(2, 5).setValue(currentProduct);
      Logger.log(currentProduct)
      Logger.log(listShirts);
      Logger.log(listCheck);

}
```